# Using a TODO-comment in androids manifest with eclispe

Tags: android, eclipse

How can I set a TODO-comment in the androids manifest, that is used by the eclipse-IDE and appears in the tasklist?

In *.java files you can use ...

```
// TODO some infotext
```

I tried ...

```
< !-- TODO some infotext -->
< !-- // TODO some infotext -->
```

both dont work for me.

Comment: I wonder what kind of TODOs there can be in a manifest?

Comment: For example: Something is not  100% clear at the moment, but I have no time to read the documents about it at the moment. I want to set a todo, so I can see that I have to keep care about it later.

Answer (score 1):

Your right, XML is same as HTML:

< ! -- This is a comment -- >

Just don't put it in middle of <.../> or you'll get a "Parser exception".

Answer (score 0):

```
            <!-- TODO change this-->
```

It's a one line comment with no space in between < and !--

Prefix TODO to add this comment into `todo` list

**Edit**
Use a shortcut **Ctrl + `/`** to add a comment in any file. It will differentiate between XML and .java files, then adds a comment accordingly.